# Targeting using Criteria ID

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-ads-api

Maybe you know if and how I can use Criteria ID taken from Adwords APi

[Here](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/geotargeting) to get targeted location and put it on map?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen anyone attempt this before, however performing a geocode on the Canonical Name column would provide you with the desired result it seems?

Geocoding docs available here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/